# Copying external disk at OS level

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, dd, linux-headers

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine. I attached external EBS volume to vm, mounted and kept in mount point. Now how to copy original  data from root to external disk? I used this command:

```bsh
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=44898303 conv=sync,noerror | pv -s 21G |sudo dd of=/dev/sda
```

But it didn't get copied.

I just want this to get copied first and then have to detach disk from current VM then attach the same disk to new VM as a root volume.

I am using this Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu server. Below are my server details.

[image]

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: What in detail means "didn't get copied"? What was the exact result of executing the command above? Were there any error messages?